# Dynamic SQL for Update does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please help me to find what's wrong with this query. Below is code snippet of a procedure from Oracle.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_Insert_ProfileStatus(
APP_EXT_CODE IN PROFILE_STATUS.APP_EXT_CODE%TYPE,
ZONE_ENV_CODE IN PROFILE_STATUS.ZONE_ENV_CODE%TYPE,
VERSION_NUMBER IN PROFILE_STATUS.VERSION_NUMBER%TYPE,
DEPLOY_STATUS IN PROFILE_STATUS.DEPLOY_STATUS%TYPE
)
IS
tmpCnt number;
tmp_query_str varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
tmp_query_str := 'select count(*) FROM PROFILE_STATUS WHERE APP_EXT_CODE =:1 '||
   ' AND ZONE_ENV_CODE =:2 AND VERSION_NUMBER =:3'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tmp_query_str
INTO tmpCnt
USING APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,VERSION_NUMBER;
dbms_output.put_line('count:'||tmpCnt);
IF tmpCnt > 0 THEN
  tmp_query_str := 'UPDATE PROFILE_STATUS SET DEPLOY_STATUS =:4 WHERE APP_EXT_CODE =:1 '||
   ' AND ZONE_ENV_CODE =:2 AND VERSION_NUMBER =:3'; 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tmp_query_str
   USING APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,VERSION_NUMBER,DEPLOY_STATUS;
ELSE
  tmp_query_str := 'INSERT INTO PROFILE_STATUS(WPS_ID,APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,'||
                   'VERSION_NUMBER,DEPLOY_STATUS)'||
                  'VALUES(SYS_GUID(),:1,:2,:3,:4)';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tmp_query_str
   USING APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,VERSION_NUMBER,DEPLOY_STATUS;
END IF;
```

**Executing Procedure :**

```
EXEC sp_Insert_ProfileStatus('APP1','PROD','1.0.1','i');result ---count:1, one row is inserted.

EXEC sp_Insert_ProfileStatus('APP1','PROD','1.0.1','u');result ---count:1, no row is affected.
```

**Update :**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_Insert_ProfileStatus(
APP_EXT_CODE IN PROFILE_STATUS.APP_EXT_CODE%TYPE,
ZONE_ENV_CODE IN PROFILE_STATUS.ZONE_ENV_CODE%TYPE,
VERSION_NUMBER IN PROFILE_STATUS.VERSION_NUMBER%TYPE,
DEPLOY_STATUS IN PROFILE_STATUS.DEPLOY_STATUS%TYPE
)
    IS
    tmpCnt number;    
    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tmpCnt FROM WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS WHERE APP_EXT_CODE =APP_EXT_CODE
        AND ZONE_ENV_CODE =ZONE_ENV_CODE AND VERSION_NUMBER =VERSION_NUMBER; 
    dbms_output.put_line('count:'||tmpCnt);
    IF tmpCnt > 0 THEN
      UPDATE WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS SET DEPLOY_STATUS =DEPLOY_STATUS WHERE APP_EXT_CODE =APP_EXT_CODE 
        AND ZONE_ENV_CODE =ZONE_ENV_CODE AND VERSION_NUMBER =VERSION_NUMBER;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS(WPS_ID,APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,VERSION_NUMBER,DEPLOY_STATUS)
       VALUES(SYS_GUID(),APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,VERSION_NUMBER,DEPLOY_STATUS);
    END IF;
    END sp_Insert_ProfileStatus;
```

Here in second part *count* comes but update is not happening. Please help me find the problem.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL at all?  There is no reason to use dynamic SQL here.  Your `UPDATE` statement has 4 bind variables but they have some odd names.  Are you expecting that `:1` is always the first value in the `using` clause?  It's not-- `using` binds values in the order they appear in the statement.  Naming a bind variable `:1` has no more impact than naming it `:foo` or `:fuzzyBunny`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and kind guidance.Do you say changing name will allow me to execute the query?

Comment: @JustinCave ,even static sql also not working.please help to check updated one.

Comment: Using column names for variables is a bad practice. `WHERE APP_EXT_CODE = APP_EXT_CODE` .For `IN` parameters use `IN_` like `WHERE APP_EXT_CODE = IN_APP_EXT_CODE`

Comment: If count is 1 then how come row got inserted?  Since 1>0 it should go to update block. Are you sure about the o/p?

Answer (score 1):

When you say `update isnt happening` you mean an error? In that case you should post that error.

In any case dont name your variable exact to the field name. Other wise you are saying `set a = a`

```
UPDATE WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS 
SET DEPLOY_STATUS = DEPLOY_STATUS 
WHERE 
    APP_EXT_CODE = APP_EXT_CODE 
AND ZONE_ENV_CODE = ZONE_ENV_CODE 
AND VERSION_NUMBER = VERSION_NUMBER;
```

Use something like this to identy what is a variable or a field. Use whatever notation you like.

```
UPDATE WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS 
SET DEPLOY_STATUS = i_DEPLOY_STATUS 
WHERE 
    APP_EXT_CODE = i_APP_EXT_CODE 
AND ZONE_ENV_CODE = i_ZONE_ENV_CODE 
AND VERSION_NUMBER = i_iVERSION_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different issues in your code.

First off, there is no reason to use dynamic SQL.  You'd only use dynamic SQL if the SQL statement you want to execute isn't known at compile time-- if you needed to determine which table to update at runtime for example.  In a well-designed application, you should almost never need dynamic SQL.

If you were going to use dynamic SQL, your `update` statement doesn't make sense.  The values in your `using` clause bound to the various bind variables in the order they appear in the statement not based on the names of the bind variables.

```
   tmp_query_str := 'UPDATE PROFILE_STATUS SET DEPLOY_STATUS =:4 WHERE APP_EXT_CODE =:1 '||
   ' AND ZONE_ENV_CODE =:2 AND VERSION_NUMBER =:3'; 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tmp_query_str
   USING APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,VERSION_NUMBER,DEPLOY_STATUS;
```

So, for example, when you say `set deploy_status = :4` but that is the first bind variable in the statement, that gets assigned the first value you pass in from the `using` clause.  In this case, you're setting the `deploy_status` to the value in `app_ext_code`, your `where` clause is comparing the value in the `app_ext_code` column against the value in the `zone_env_code` parameter, etc.

If you were going to use dynamic SQL for some reason, you'd want to specify the parameters in the correct order in your `using` clause

```
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE tmp_query_str
   USING deploy_status, APP_EXT_CODE,ZONE_ENV_CODE,VERSION_NUMBER;
```

But, like I said, it doesn't make any sense to use dynamic SQL here when static SQL does the job.  The problem that you'll have when you get rid of the dynamic SQL, though, is that your parameter names are likely poorly chosen.  Most developers and projects ensure that parameters and local variables don't share the name of a database column because otherwise you generally end up with name resolution issues.

In your second example, whey you write

```
UPDATE WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS 
   SET DEPLOY_STATUS =DEPLOY_STATUS 
 WHERE APP_EXT_CODE =APP_EXT_CODE       
   AND ZONE_ENV_CODE =ZONE_ENV_CODE 
   AND VERSION_NUMBER =VERSION_NUMBER;
```

your goal, presumably, is to compare the data in the `app_ext_code` column against the value passed in as the `app_ext_code` parameter.  But that's not what your code does.  Instead, both `app_ext_code` references resolve to the column in the table not to the parameter.  So your update is, realistically, updating every row in the table and just setting the `deploy_status` to the existing value in the table regardless of the value that you pass in.  Similarly, your `select count(*)` is going to count every row in the table where the `app_ext_code`, `zone_env_code`, and `version_number` are `not null` regardless of whether they have the values that you're passing in.

The most common way to avoid this is to use a consistent prefix or suffix for parameters and local variables that differentiates them from the names of columns.  For example, I use `p_` as a prefix for parameter names and `l_` as a prefix for local variables.  So something like

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_Insert_ProfileStatus(
  P_APP_EXT_CODE IN PROFILE_STATUS.APP_EXT_CODE%TYPE,
  P_ZONE_ENV_CODE IN PROFILE_STATUS.ZONE_ENV_CODE%TYPE,
  P_VERSION_NUMBER IN PROFILE_STATUS.VERSION_NUMBER%TYPE,
  P_DEPLOY_STATUS IN PROFILE_STATUS.DEPLOY_STATUS%TYPE
)
IS
  tmpCnt number;    
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO tmpCnt 
    FROM WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS 
   WHERE APP_EXT_CODE = P_APP_EXT_CODE
     AND ZONE_ENV_CODE = P_ZONE_ENV_CODE 
     AND VERSION_NUMBER = P_VERSION_NUMBER; 
  dbms_output.put_line('count:'||tmpCnt);
  IF tmpCnt > 0 
  THEN
    UPDATE WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS 
       SET DEPLOY_STATUS = P_DEPLOY_STATUS 
     WHERE APP_EXT_CODE = P_APP_EXT_CODE 
       AND ZONE_ENV_CODE = P_ZONE_ENV_CODE 
       AND VERSION_NUMBER = P_VERSION_NUMBER;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS(WPS_ID,
                                    APP_EXT_CODE,
                                    ZONE_ENV_CODE,
                                    VERSION_NUMBER,
                                    DEPLOY_STATUS)       
      VALUES(SYS_GUID(),
             P_APP_EXT_CODE,
             P_ZONE_ENV_CODE,
             P_VERSION_NUMBER,
             P_DEPLOY_STATUS);
  END IF;
END sp_Insert_ProfileStatus;
```

If you really want parameter names to be the same as column names, you can also explicitly qualify the parameter names in all your code by prefixing them with the name of the procedure

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO tmpCnt 
    FROM WAF1_PROFILE_STATUS 
   WHERE APP_EXT_CODE = sp_Insert_ProfileStatus.APP_EXT_CODE
     AND ZONE_ENV_CODE = sp_Insert_ProfileStatus.ZONE_ENV_CODE 
     AND VERSION_NUMBER = sp_Insert_ProfileStatus.VERSION_NUMBER;
```

That approach, though, generates code that is far too verbose for my liking.

Comment: I don't agree with statement "In a well-designed application, you should almost never need dynamic SQL." In a datawarehouse application with 1000+ tables you are happy to use dynamic SQL

Comment: @Wernfried - Maybe we disagree about what "almost never" means.  Certainly, there are cases where dynamic SQL is useful in well-designed applications.  There are cases where it is useful in building warehouse loads.  But I consider that sort of application to be the exception that proves the rule particularly when talking to someone that appears to be relatively new to at least PL/SQL.